# Cassandra iterate over elements of set

Tags: cassandra, cql

I need to move data from one table to another, but tables definition is a bit different:

```
CREATE TABLE elements (
    id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
    other_ids set<text>,
    name text
) 

CREATE TABLE elements_new (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    other_id text,
    name text
)
```

I need to create a row in new table for each set element of old table.

How to iterate over elements of set in cql statement? I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this only by programming - there is no support for this in CQL.

Depending on the amount of data you may need either to use [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/), or write your code that will go through all token ranges, fetch data & rework them into new structure.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use paging in Cassandra for iterating over a query. Paging is available in most clients. For Java driver look here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/paging/

Answer (score 1):

I think your new table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE elements_new (
    id text,
    name text STATIC,
    other_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id), other_id)
)
```

Then each id will have a name and a set of unique other_ids.

This is functionally the exact same as other table with exception that you can iterate through each other id with normal driver pager that can be controlled with the Statement's fetchSize.

with CQL collections the entire thing needs to be brought into memory and sent over as a single column. There is no paging through it.